# Flow: Object type with no parameter can't be assigned to object type with optional parameter

Tags: javascript, flowtype

While working with Flow typing, I assumed it should be OK to assign an object of a type without a particular parameter to a variable of a type with an optional parameter. This is not so.

Please see the code below...

```
// @flow

type T1 = {
  +a: string,
  +b? : number,
};

type T2 = {
  +a: string,
}

const t2: T2 = {
  a: "Hello",
};

const v1 : T1 = t2;    // ERROR!!! (Why???)

const v2 : T1 = {      // THIS WORKS
  ...t2
};
```

Since in T1 the 'b' property is optional, why should Flow prevent me from assigning another type where 'b' is simply omitted? This restriction seems unnecessary and unhelpful.

Does anyone understand the rationale behind this behavior or can point to some documentation that explains it. I've read through the Flow Objects section and found nothing there: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/

Comment: Flow will throw error "Cannot assign `t2` to `v1` because property `b` is missing in `T2` [1] but exists in `T1` [2]." that's normal and correct. `b` is an optional property of type `T1`, but `T1` type is different than type `T2`. hm take a look https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxiVo9AXATwAcBTMAFQEYwBeMAb1TDAGoBDALjAGc8AnAJYA7AOYAaJqwBGAfjBchAVwC2UknwkBfANz5iZcgCZaDAD6T2XXoNETTm9AGM4Q3mDyGuRk42acwAEQAEiQw8AFauqjOrnhgAG7UXtR0HtrMzJhgAKIASrkA8rkAhKVgABQA6gAWBDL1AJROLm7xxsk+GRlZ5EEAkgDKYJVFANIDkgB00x6oOkA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of [@Marko Savic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57132494/11308639):

The inexact object type fails because Flow cannot know what type for property `b` an object of type `T2` will have. For example, we could have `const bad_t2: T2 = { a: 'string', b: 'also string' }`. This should make it clear that we cannot assign `bad_t2` to a variable of type `T1` because `b` is type `string`, which conflicts with the definition of `T1`. However, when making `T2` exact, Flow can guarantee that property `b` will not be on an object of type `T2` and, thus, will not conflict with `T1`.

Answer (score 0):

As i said inside comments `T1` and `T2` are two different types, because `T1` has an optional prop `b`.

```
type T1 = {
  +a: string,
  +b?: number,
}

type T2 = {
  +a: string,
}

const t2: T2 = {
  a: "Hello",
};

const v1 : T1 = t2;
```

**Flow error:**

*Cannot assign `t2` to `v1` because property `b` is missing in `T2` but exists in `T1`.* and that's correct!

Solution for this will be to use `exact type` of `T2`.

```
type T2 = {|
  +a: string,
|}
```

Take a look at [Exact object types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types).

Now when you have `T2` as exact object you can say:

```
const v1 : T1 = t2; // THAT'S OK!
```

Because `t2` satisfied minimal representation of type `T1`.

[FlowTry Example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxiVo9AXATwAcBTMAFQEYwBeMAb1TDAGoBDALjAGc8AnAJYA7AOYAaJqwBGAfjBchAVwC2UknwkBfANz5iZcgCZaDAD6T2XXoNETTm9AGM4Q3mDyGuRk42acwAEQAEiQw8AFauqjOrnhgAG7UXtR0HtrMzJgUQQCSAMpgAOoA8gBKANJ5Ti5u8cbJPhkZWeS5BSUVVcwAdL0eqDpAA)

Comment: One thing to note is that the inexact object type fails because Flow cannot know what type for property `b` an object of type `T2` will have. For example, we could have `const bad_t2: T2 = { a: 'string', b: 'also string' }`. This should make it clear that we cannot assign `bad_t2` to a variable of type `T1` because `b` is type `string`, which conflicts with the definition of `T1`. However, when making `T2` exact, Flow can guarantee that property `b` will not be on an object of type `T2` and, thus, will not conflict with `T1`.

Comment: @user11307804 This actually exactly the answer I was looking for - why it would make sense to disallow the assignment. Yes it makes sense now. If you move your comment to an answer, I will mark that as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Marko Savic I also appreciated your answer - didn't know that making it exact causes it to work. Thanks.